# What's wrong with the HAVING clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've tried to write the following query with `HAVING` clause to avoid writing a subquery and therefore make the query a little bit less readable.:

```
SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id 
FROM account
GROUP BY partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id
HAVING MAX(date) = date
```

I need to get all rows, grouped by what I specified in the `GROUP BY` clause having the `max date`. But I got the error about

```
ERROR:  column "account.date" must appear in 
the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I used it in the aggregate function. What's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `where max(date) = date`? If you want to use `having`, you have to group by the column in the `having` clause.

Comment: @Smutje aggregates are not allowed in the where clause

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want one row per group (the row with the maximum date)? If yes, windowing functions (as suggested by Damien_The_Unbeliever) are the way to go. If not, please add sample input and expected output to your question.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I thought I was clear about what I asked. I tried to use aggregates in the HAving clause but failed. Why did I fail?

Comment: Let me rephrase: What is the goal of your query? Do you want to get the rows whose date equals the max date for their group? Or the rows whose date equals the global max date?
Your error is that you assume `HAVING` applies to rows before the grouping. Think of `HAVING` as a `WHERE` clause for groups - then it should become clear why your query - as it currently stands - cannot work.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt As I wrote __I neede to get all rows, grouped by what I specified in the GROUP BY clause having the max date.__

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) to assign row numbers (or ranks if you want to take the tied topmost rows):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id
       ORDER BY date desc) as rn
  FROM account
  ) as t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do that with just having, isn't it?

Comment: @user3663882 - no. Within each clause, the same column expression has to mean the same thing. But in your example, you want on the left of the equals, the `date` value within `MAX(date)` to mean "the `date` values for all rows" and on the right of the equals, `date` to mean "the `date` value for a specific row".

Comment: Let me ask you about windows functions in general. We can use them if we want to do some with the specific partition of a result set, right?

Comment: The query is not exactly correct as it stands now. We should have added partitioning by columns I had needed in the group by cluase.

Comment: @user3663882 - I wasn't clear on whether that grouping was required or was just an artefact of your attempt to use an aggregate. Changed now.

Comment: BTW Why can't we just write something like this `SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date desc) as rn
FROM partner.daily_player_account
WHERE rn = 1`. SQL server keeps telling me that the coumn rn deosn't exsist.

Comment: @user3663882 - because logically, both `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are processed before the `SELECT` clause. A better question would be why we're not allowed to use a window function directly in the `WHERE` clause, for which, unfortunately, I have no good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id 
FROM account
GROUP BY date, partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id
HAVING MAX(date) = date
```

Here you forget to add date (column name) in group by clause.

Please let me know, is this works for you?

Comment: Wrong, grouping by date doesn't get the result I need in.

Comment: @user3663882 use below query if you have multiple records of given max date: 'code'(SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id 
FROM account
GROUP BY date, partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM account))

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because grouping the coulmns you specified gives you the result equivalent to `SELECT partner_id, player_id, currency_id, platform_id FROM account`. Grouping by all columns, in fact.

Comment: Grouping is added in case if you have other columns in your table than this grouping columns, and you want to group records by these listed columns.